# Error while capturing a view as an Image in android

Tags: android

I have a big problem that I am capturing a view into a Bitmap image but the view is unable to be accessed. Means We unable to get its height or width. Please suggest me where is the problem?

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@color/Red">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_Previrew_Header"
            android:text="Greeting" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></TextView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fr"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_email"
            android:background="@drawable/email2x" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></Button>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_Preview_Image"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="270dip" android:layout_width="250dip"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_Preview_Greeting"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:textColor="@color/Red" android:textSize="20dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_marginTop="40dip"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/halosys_logo_bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginTop="320dip" android:layout_marginRight="40dip"></ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fr);
 Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
          bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/image.jpg"));
```

**Error Stack:**

```
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.greetingApp.common/com.greetingApp.common.Greeting}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at com.greetingApp.common.Greeting.SaveData(Greeting.java:109)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at com.greetingApp.common.Greeting.onCreate(Greeting.java:81)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-28 17:16:17.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you run your code in your Activity.onCreate method? If yes, then at this point the dimensions of your views are not yet known. You should execute this code at some later stage, when your layout size has been calculated

Comment: Which point of activity lifecycle do you refer to as the last?

Comment: means as the last statement of onCreate method.

Comment: As I pointed out, the dimensions of your views are not known in OnCreate method. They are laid out at later stages of your activity lifecycle. Therefore you need to move your code to a later stage in your activity life. So, for example you can check your view's width and height in some button OnClick listener method

Comment: Thanks Anton but before your this suggestion I tried the same but sorry to say error remains same, view height still gives 0